# Run Linux Commands Using PHP

Tags: php, linux, exec, redhat

I have seen many questions about Running `Linux` Commands using `PHP`, but my problem is different. I am using a shared hosting `Linux` server, and I want to install a package called `Poppler-utils` using `PHP` code, because i have no access to the `Linux` command-line. First I tried to figure out the `Distro` using `cat /proc/version` and this is the output:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-604.30.3.lve1.3.63.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@build.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sun Sep 27 06:34:10 EDT 2015
```

So I assumed it's `Redhat` Distro based on the output above. So I tried to install the `Poppler-Utils` Package using:

```
exec('yum install poppler-utils',$buffer); 
echo implode($buffer);
```

As mentioned in [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/converter-pdf-files-to-text-format-command/) article.

> install pdftotext under RedHat / RHEL / Fedora / CentOS Linux
>
> pdftotext is installed using poppler-utils package under various Linux
>   distributions:
>
> `# yum install poppler-utils`
>
> OR use the following under Debian / Ubuntu Linux
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install poppler-utils`

But nothing happens at all. So how can I install `Poppler-utils` in `/usr/local/bin/` ?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Contact your hosting company, you probably don't have permission.

Comment: If you are denied command line access, perhaps they also denied you `exec` access..

Comment: But I tried exec('whoami'); and it worked!

Comment: Yes, but asking information about yourself is something else than requesting super user rights to install a package.

Comment: `yum install` requires admin/root/sudo access. It's like on windows when you create a limited user, you can do stuff but not install applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have sudo / root privileges on shared hosting to install files. The only option is to contact your hosting company and to ask for them to install it on the server.

You cant run `exec` on commands you don't have access to the function e.g. `yum` or `apt-get` ;).

Comment: Even if `Safe mode` is `disabled`?

Comment: Unless the user your account on the hosting has admin rights / in the sudo file / permitted some other way then you cant access those commands.

Comment: It's all about permissions, it doesn't matter if `exec` works.

Answer (score 1):

The're no way without root or `sudo` access. But you can download binaries into your home directory (~/local-bin/ for example) and run stuff from here (don't forget to add `~/local-bin` to PATH environment, `export PATH=$PATH":~/local-bin"`). But the best way - create ticket to support, maybe they can install some packages for you. Or just use Docker on small vps/vds - it's simple and cheap.

Comment: Yea, I will be contacting the hosting support, thank you!